# Usar un listview para tener un registro de un boton

Tags: android, android-studio

Alguien sabe si podría usar un listview de un activity para llevar un registro de un botón (que se encuentra en otro activity) de las veces que ha sido apretado por ejemplo;

-Conectado
-Conectado
-Desconectado
-Conectado

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow! Sin saber mucho de Android me imagino que si ya que pasar información de un Activity a otro no es gran cosa. En google podras encontrar ejemplos de un activity modificando otro cuando se pulsa un boton

Answer (score 0):

eso es bastante sencillo de hacer. Lo que tienes que hacer es buscar en youtube o google, como pasar datos de una actividad a otra. Cuando descubras que se pasan por medio del método putExtra, a este mismo deberás pasarle como argumento una variable de tipo entero que previamente haya contado los clics del botón. Para contar los clics del botón también hay tutoriales en youtube en inglés. Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Se te agradece el aporte pero esto parece mas un comentario/recomendación que una respuesta en si, te invito a leer [answer], pues la idea de la zona de respuestas es aportar una solución al problema expuesto